# Web model does not contain a definition in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting an error in my MVC project that goes like this:

> 'xxx.xxx.xxx.MarketplaceViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'MarketplaceCategories' and no extension method 'MarketplaceCategories' accepting a first argument of type 'xxx.xxx.xxx.MarketplaceViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am trying to access it in a view that is laid out like this

```
@model xxx.xxx.xxx.MarketplaceViewModel
<div class="mp-options">
            <span class="pull-left">
                @foreach (var item in Model.MarketplaceCategories)
                {
                    <a class="mp-category filter" data-filter=".category-1" href="#">@item.Name</a>
                }

            </span>
            <a href="#" class="mp-icon mp-grid mp-selected" data-view="mp-view-grid">Grid View</a>
            <a href="#" class="mp-icon mp-list" data-view="mp-view-list">List View</a>
        </div>
        <div id="app-container"><!--App Display-->
            <div class="mix category-1" data-my-order="1">
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.MarketplaceItems)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <a class="mp-image mp-box-img" href="#">
                                <img src="@Url.Action("Image", new { id = @item.Id})" height="50">
                            </a>
                            <h3 class="mp-title">@item.Name</h3>
                            <div class="mp-price">@item.MinimumPrice.ToString("C") - @item.MaximumPrice.ToString("C")</div>
                            <div class="mp-details">
                                @item.Description
                            </div>
                            <a class="mp-icon mp-add" href="#">Add to cart</a>
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!--/App Display-->
```

The second foreach works fine but the `Model.MarketplaceCategories` seems to be the one that is causing problems.  I get the errror above.  This is the model

```
public class MarketplaceViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MarketplaceCategory> MarketplaceCategories;
    public List<MarketplaceItem> MarketplaceItems { get; set; }
}
```

The MarketplaceCategory objects are like this

```
public class MarketplaceCategory : xxxObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

What am i missing that would cause this error?  I also made another view model specifically for the categories

```
public class MarketplaceCategoryViewModel
{
    public List<MarketplaceCategory> MarketplaceCategories { get; set; } 
}
```

Would it be easier to use that model instead?  But then i'd need two models on one page.

Comment: are you sure that namespace is correct, and that you don't have another viewmodel in a different namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MarketplaceCategories` is a field, not a property. Change your model to

```
public class MarketplaceViewModel
{
  public IEnumerable<MarketplaceCategory> MarketplaceCategories { get; set; } // add get and set
  public List<MarketplaceItem> MarketplaceItems { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, when I do that though I get a null reference, when I know my database has fields for this.

Comment: Can you show the line of code that is generating that exception, and also how you are populating the property. And you can always just test it by initializing the property in the GET method - model.MarketplaceCategories  = new List<MarketplaceCategory>();` - and adding a few dummy items

Comment: `@foreach (var item in Model.MarketplaceCategories)` is generating that exception.  The property is populated from the database through the model